# EditText input type textCapSentences not working on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop, android-xml

I have implemeted `android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapSentences"` in my xml code. When I run it on **kitkat**, **textCapSentence** works fine but when build is run on **Lollipop** device it does not work. Anybody knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hi this is because in lollipop if you have disabled Auto - Capitalization in keyboard settings then you can't enable it programmatically.

here are the steps:-

- Tap icon of ‘Settings’ on the Home screen of your Android Lollipop Device
- At the ‘Settings’ screen, scroll down to the PERSONAL section and tap the ‘Language & input’ section.
- At the ‘Language & input’ section, select your keyboard(which is marked as current keyboard).
- Now tap the ‘Preferences’.
- Tap to check the ‘Auto – Capitalization’ to enable it.
- That’s all!

Answer (score 6):

Set this way,

```
EditText input = (EditText).findViewById(R.id.ID);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these two attributes. It works.

```
 android:capitalize="sentences"
 android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. Also capitalized is depricated.

Answer (score 2):

Set input type in XML as well as in JAVA file like this,

In XML,

> android:inputType="textCapSentences"

and in JAVA file,

```
edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

This worked for me and make sure your keyboard's **Auto-Capitalization** setting is **Enabled**.

Answer (score 0):

On which devices and OS specific versions are you trying. Sometime the manufactures are overriding the "`InputMethod`" on the OS level and it's just not working.

you can also make a test by taking the sources of the `EditText` from google code and compile it as your `EditTextCustom` and see if it's working.